# Alternatives to database connection class

Tags: php, database, class, caching, mysqli

I am pretty much a novice in PHP and I need help resolving a recent problem I've encountered.

I'm building a project that is built using PHP on server side and HTML5 on front end, while
all the data is retrieved using MySQLi.

For example: **Title, Description, Image, Background color** etc...

I understand the basic logic of the database. My page consists of only the four elements I stated in the example above, how do I make the communication with the database in the most efficient way?

- Do I make a function page that consist of many generic function for any page element I might need to pull from the database? When do I open and close each communication with the database?
- Or maybe use some sort of **DatabaseHandlerClass** like [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29555/php-framework-building-database-control-classes) in order to cache all the queries needed for a specific page load
  and then open a connection query them all and close the connection?

Keep in mind I need it to be as generic and scalable as possible. Any tip and recommendation would help a lot.

**Update**

```
<?php


$name_query = "SELECT name FROM `template1` WHERE `user_id` = 1";
global $name;

if ($result = $mysqli->query($name_query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $name = $obj->name;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

**do I need to write this code each time I need a new set of data? can you specify how opening connection is done efficiently?**

Answer (score 1):

Use a shared config file to open the db connection, and `include` it in the top of each script that needs to access the data.

Then just query the data each time you need a new set of data.

Database queries are not a big overhead - that's a common misconception - although opening connections should be done efficiently to avoid hitting max connection limits.